# Django Background Img CSS

Tags: python, css, django, background-image

My background image is not loading though my CSS file. It loads through the front end with:

```html
<img class="top" src={% static "/store/img/store.jpg" %}>
```

inside of a div but not with: background:  url('{{ STATIC_URL }}/store/img/store.jpg'); on the css file.

My path is apps/store/static/store/img/store.jpg, so that's good.

HTML:

```html
<div class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style="max-width:1600px;min-width:500px" id="home">
  <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-padding-large w3-opacity">
    <h1>SAN MIGUEL'S EXPORTA</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home{
    /* The image used */
background:  url('{{ STATIC_URL }}/store/img/store.jpg') no-repeat;

/* Full height */
height: 100%;

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django's standard templating engine you need to load the static files before referencing them. Paste `{% load static %}` before `<img class="top" src={% static "/store/img/store.jpg" %}>`

More help with static files here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Feel free to ask more questions to me if you want!

Comment: {% load static %} is there. I am able to load images through the HTML BUT not through the CSS file. How do I load it?  #home{
   
    background-image:  url('store/img/store.jpg') no-repeat;  }    .....  this is not working

Comment: I don't think it is possible through the CSS file, why not just do it in the HTML? Try `background:  {% static "/store/img/store.jpg" %} no-repeat;
`